# Is it possible to connect between NetworkManager (HLAPI) in Unity3D and socket server?

Tags: sockets, unity-game-engine

I try to connect between NetworkManager (HLAPI) in Unity3D and Socket server.

I have already tried to connect two Unity applications using HLAPI or LLAPI. It works well. But HLAPI or LLAPI Unity client can't connect to Socket server (python).

I think that HLAPI or LLAPI supports to connect among Unity3D applications. Is it right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to connect between NetworkManager (HLAPI) in Unity3D
>   and socket server?

The short answer is **No**.

These are two different protocols.

I once tried it. It seems to connect secretly then immediately disconnect. I can't remember if I tried it with TCP or UDP but you can't just do that.

*HLAPI* or *LLAPI* are built on on top of the UDP protocol and possibly TCP too in newer Unity version. In order to connect to it with an application **not** made with Unity, you will have to reverse engineer the HLAPI or LLAPI protocol and understand how they both connect to each other(Handshake) then build a custom API for python using raw socket.

If you want to communicate between Unity and a program made with python, I suggest you use standard socket (TCP/UPD). This is more less hassle and will allow your app to work with any language that supports socket.