# What are the IP protocol/specifications for Unity3D Client-Server?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Unity Clients and Unity Servers use TCP/IP to communicate.
I would like to have those specifications and write a Java (not C# or JS)  construct (HTTP/REST?) on a Linux box to communicate and control players on Unity Servers (and clients).
And are there any examples of this being already done?

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42358971/is-it-possible-to-connect-between-networkmanager-hlapi-in-unity3d-and-socket-s/42359260#42359260)

Comment: You just saved me. Thank you. My boss wants this to happen. I didn't think it was possible for exactly the reason laid out in your link. Thanks.

Comment: Nope not possible unless you can do reverse engineering to reverse Unity's unet protocol. This will take time and won't worth it since a simple Unity update can destroy your work. The best thing to do is to use a standard protocols like TCP/UDP in the game then you can communicate with it with Java. You're welcome

Comment: "...communicate with it with Java."
By using HLAPI, LLAPI, and UnityWebRequest?
Or is there a better approach?

Comment: Not HLAPI or LLAPI.  By using TCP/UDP with the Socket API. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36526332/simple-socket-server-in-unity/36526634#36526634) for an example.